# AWS price list based on region and currency

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are calling the [AWS PriceList API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-list-api-update-regional-price-lists/) with the URL specified and getting data in JSON format. Based on the offer index file, we are retrieving offers.

For an example: To access Amazon EC2 products we are retrieving data from:

```
https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/us-east-1/index.json
```

Now the region is `us-east-1`. If we want to download the offer file for a specific service (say for Amazon EC2) in a specific region (say us-east-2) then we are trying to fetch data from:

```
https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/us-east-2/index.json
```

However, it is giving `Access denied`. What should we do in order to call the API passing region and currency?

Comment: Have this other region's modules been configured to have the correct security groups?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like working now

Checkout:
https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/us-east-1/index.json

Answer (score 0):

yes.region wise price listing is working now.but my another requirement is price listing based on the currency of that region.
Right now everytime i am getting prices in USD rather than its region's currency.for an example,i should get prices in AUD if the region is Asia Pacific (Sydney).
how to get different currency wise prices for price list?

Comment: All list prices for AWS services are in USD. While it is possible to obtain *billing* in other currencies, that is always a conversion from USD at the end of the month at the prevailing exchange rate. You cannot obtain a price list in any currency other than USD.